# Install apt package via Chef solo and Vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, chef-infra

I need to install `libgmp3-dev` package for Ubuntu,

Vagrant file:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = ["chef/site-cookbooks", "cookbooks"]
    chef.add_recipe "build-essential"
    chef.add_recipe "apt"
  end
end
```

chef/site-cookbooks/system/recipes/default.rb:

```
package 'libgmp3-dev' do
  action :install
end
```

But when I created a virtual machine, there is no `libgmp3-dev` inside.

**Update.** found this solution:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => 'sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev -y'
```

But I think it's not a very good solution

Comment: I definitely agree that using the shell provisioner is not a very good solution for installing software. It's not completely clear if you have your own `system` cookbook or if you're using the one from the Supermarket, but you have answers below that should help you either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the [`system` cookbook from Supermarket](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/system), you need to include the `system::install_packages` recipe and set the `node['system']['packages']['install']` attribute:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = ["chef/site-cookbooks", "cookbooks"]
    chef.add_recipe "build-essential"
    chef.add_recipe "apt"

    chef.add_recipe "system::install_packages"
    chef.json = {
      "system" => {
        "packages" => {
          "install" => ["libgmp3-dev"]
        }
      }
    }
  end
end
```

If you are using your own `system` cookbook with that `package` instruction you have pasted, I think [the solution proposed by Patrick Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34573221/3284723) should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Vagrant docs for the Chef Solo provisioner](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_solo.html), it looks like you're missing a recipe in your Vagrantfile...

```
chef.add_recipe "system"
```

Comment: Added "system" recipe to my vagrantfile, but it didn't help. Do I need also to add something like this `system::install_packages` ? [Link for this recipe](https://github.com/xhost-cookbooks/system)

Comment: I wonder if there's a name collision issue with the system cookbook in Chef Supermarket. Could you try renaming the `system` folder in `site-cookbooks` and then update the `chef.add_recipe` line in your Vagrantfile accordingly?